# How to fix dependency issues with VSCode, Godot using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, godot

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. To install Godot (mono version) on this OS, you must install `mono-complete`. I do most of my development in VSCode and would like to use it with Godot. However, the c# plugin for VSCode requires `.net core`. Installing `.net core` via `sudo snap install dotnet-runtime-31 --classic` and creating an alias breaks Godot.

I've suppressed the errors from the c# plugin, but is there a way to get both these packages working, or to force VSCode to use `mono-complete`? What am I losing if I continue to suppress these error messages?